# Throwing an exception as const&

Tags: c++, exception, constants

Take the following code;

```
void DoThrow( const std::exception& e )
{
    throw e;
}

int main( int nArgs, char* args[] )
{
    std::exception e;
    try
    {
        DoThrow( e );
    }
    catch( std::exception& e )
    {
        // const exception ref is caught
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to retrofit const correctness in my project and inadvertently created the above situation.  As it stands, in Dev Studio the catch block DOES catch the exception, despite the fact that it is thrown as a const & but caught as a non-const &.

Question - Should it?  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`throw` takes an expression and creates via copy-initialization an exception object based on the static type of that expression. The exception object is not a `const` object.

The `catch` statement initializes a reference to the exception object, not the object (if any) referred to by the `throw` expression.

Comment: In short, you don't catch the same object `e` as is given to `DoThrow(e)`.

Comment: That's the one - cheers!  (And also this means you should take care to re-throw with 'throw;' not 'throw e;')

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about what the specification says, but it seems to me that in practice, an exception is dispatched to the correct "catch" block using RTTI (some compiler synthesised code must do this), to which "const" is irrelevant.

Comment: To be clear, as far as `typeid` is concerned, the top-level cv-qualifiers (`const` and `volatile`) are discarded. However I don't think this is the issue here and would more lean toward Charles' answer.